# Refactoring strategy for the class which generates specific text file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, tdd

I am a TDD noob and I don't know how to solve the following problem.
I have pretty large class which generates text file in a specific format, for import into the external system. I am going to refactor this class and I want to write unit tests before.

How should these tests look like? Actually the main goal - do not break the structure of the file. But this does not mean that I should compare the contents of the file before and after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would benefit from a test that I would hesitate to call a "unit test" - although arguably it tests the current text-file-producing "unit".  This would simply run the current code and do a diff between its output and a "golden master" file (which you could generate by running the test once and copying to its designated location).  If there is much conditional behavior in the code, you may want to run this with several examples, each a different test case.  With the existing code, by definition, all the tests should pass.

Now start to refactor.  Extract a method - or better, write a test for a method that you can envision extracting, a true unit test - extract the method, and ensure that all tests, for the new small method and for the bigger system, still pass.  Lather, rinse, repeat.  The system tests give you a safety net that lets you go forward in the refactoring with confidence; the unit tests drive the design of the new code.

There are libraries available to make this kind of testing easier (although it's pretty easy even without them).  See http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

In such a case I use the following strategy:

- Write a test for each method (just covering its default behavior without any error handling etc.)
- Run a code coverage tool and find the blocks not covered by the tests. Write tests covering these blocks.
- Do this until you get a code coverage of over 80%
- Start refactoring the class (mostly generate smaller classes following the separation of concern principle).
- Use Test Driven Development for writing the new classes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's a pretty good place to start (comparing a well known output against what is being generated by the current class).
If the single generator class can produce different results, then create one for each case.
This will ensure that you are not breaking your current generator class.

One thing that might help you is if you have the specification document for the current class.  You can use that as the base of your refactoring effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet, pick up a copy of Michael Feathers' book "[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)". It's all about how to add tests to existing code, which is exactly what you're looking for.

But until you finish reading the book, I'd suggest starting with a regression test: create the class, have it write the file to disk, and then compare that file to a "known good" file that you've stashed in your source repository somewhere. If they don't match, fail the test.

Then start looking at the interesting decisions that your class makes. See how you can get them under test. Maybe you extract some complicated if-conditions into public functions that return bool, and you write a battery of tests to prove that, given the right inputs, that function returns the right value. Maybe generation of a particular string has some interesting logic; start testing it.

Along the way, you may find objects that want to get out. For example, you may find that the code (or the tests!) would be simpler if there was a separate class that generates a single line of output. Go with it. You've got your regression test to catch you if you screw anything up.

Work relentlessly to remove dependencies (but make sure you've got a higher-level test, like a regression test, to catch you if you make mistakes). If your class creates its own FileStream and writes to the filesystem, change it to take a TextWriter in its constructor instead, so you can write tests that pass in a StringWriter and never touch the file system. Once that's done, you can get rid of the old test that writes a file to disk (but only if you didn't break it while trying to write the new test!) If your class needs a database connection, refactor until you can write a test that passes in fake data. Etc.